# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes' or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2022, equality, access-denied

This happened in Visual Studio 2022 Community version.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied. File name: 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. 
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Tried to create deleting Fakes folder and rebuilding my solution. Nothing.
Created [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] just gave more details of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that my solution build attempted to create the microsoft.qualitytools.testing.fakes, but there was already a dll in the bin folder. Deleted it and the build worked.